# How to use css sprites in this kind of menu?

Tags: css, sprite

I've been trying to use css sprites in this [MENU](http://www.binarywaste.com/profile/user/seinkraft) intead of simple icons for each menu item without any luck because it need a 16px widht setted. But if i do that the whole thing get messed (the li specificaly).

The image sprite is located [HERE](http://www.binarywaste.com/theme/images/icons/menu.png) but i dont know wnought css to make it work by myself, i've been trying without luck and without affect the current functionality. (the li ul need to have a widht of auto to get the parent widht and auto adjust to the spans).

Please i need help with this :(.

SOLUTION: CSS

```
.nav li a{

line-height: 16px; /* new position */
position: relative; /* new position */
padding-left: 24px; /* new position */

}

.iconized i{
background: url("images/icons/menu.png") no-repeat scroll transparent;
display: inline-block;
height: 16px;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 16px;
margin-right: 3px;

position: absolute;  /* new position */
left: 5px;/* new position */
}

.iconized li .user{
background-position: -2px -2px;
}
```

SOLUTION: HTML

```
<ul class="nav iconized left">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="user"></i><span>Profile</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Site looks nice. But which menu do you refer to? The tabs or the rollover menu on the top?

Comment: that one of the user (with the galery, scraps, and such).

Answer (score 1):

An image sprite is just an image that is only partially displayed. This is achieved by creating an element (usually a div, but can be other element as well). You give the element a fixed width and height (16px in your case). 
Then you use the background css property to put a part of the image in the background of the element. By setting the `background-position` css property, you can define which part of the image is displayed, by specifying the coordinates of the background image pixel that should be in the left top corner of your element.

So in you css you write something like this:

```
.icon {
    background-image: url('yoursprite.png');
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.icon.i1 {
    background-position: 0 0; /* Second image on the first row */
}
.icon.i2 {
    background-position: 0, -16px; /* Second image on the first row */
}
/* Etc */
```

And in your HTML you write this:

```
<div class="icon i1"></div>
<div class="icon i2"></div>
<div class="icon i3"></div>
<div class="icon i4"></div>
```

This way, each div will display a different part of the image in its background.

Comment: Yeah i've tried that but as i said i need that applied to the current style without bug it.

Comment: You can't. You will need a container with fixed width and height. The easiest possibility I see, is put a second span inside the menu span that now contains the text and the image. Set `display:inline-block` to allow giving it a proper width and height, and assign the image to that span instead of the span that now contains both text and image. You cannot actually clip a bit from the image and position that small image somewhere in the background of a larger span.

Comment: I've already tried taht without luck. If you try it yourself you'll see the problem.

Comment: In that case, you'd better post what you've tried and how that looked (put it online somewhere). You can't expect people to download your whole site and start debugging from scratch because you didn't have any luck. :)

Comment: Well i've solved myself, maybe not the best solution, but it work on all browsers. Anyways, thanks you. Also i've updated the question with the solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I described, only changed the css class names and modified the pixel positions a bot. :-p